# How to use background with linear gradient in Tailwind css

Tags: css, reactjs, background, tailwind-css

i want to use this color in my background

```
linear-gradient(355.45deg, #FFFFFF 11.26%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 95.74%)
```

i know that how to this color in my background using css. but how to use this color using tailwind css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `bg-[...]` and put your custom color or what you want inside `[]`, in tailwind you can also use same way to give custom attributes to more things

Comment: No. we cant to use linear gradient in that way.

Comment: then maybe this link can help https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/background-image#linear-gradients